# Clickable hypertext within PySimpleGUI table created from list

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a PySimpleGUI table updating from a list.  In that list, the first item is a website link.  How can I make PySimpleGUI recognise them as clickable links within it's table?  I have the following code which creates the table from a list that is updating periodically, column 1 contains websites that I would like clickable:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def getData():
    #data update code that creates a new list every x secs
    return [("https://www.google.com", "Google", "10", "5445", "No"),("https://www.yahoo.com", "yahoo", "2", "333", "Yes")]

dat = getData()
headings = ["Link", "Name", "Users", "Id", "Authorized"]

sg.set_options(dpi_awareness=True)
layout = [

    [sg.Table(values=dat, headings=headings, max_col_width=25,
              auto_size_columns=True,
              enable_events=True,
              # display_row_numbers=True,
              justification='right',
              num_rows=20,
              alternating_row_color=sg.theme_button_color()[1],
              key='-TABLE-',
              # selected_row_colors='red on yellow',
              # enable_events=True,
              # select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE,
              expand_x=True,
              expand_y=True,
              enable_click_events=True,  # Comment out to not enable header and other clicks
              )],
]
window = sg.Window('Table Element - Example 1', layout, resizable=True, finalize=True)
while True:
    dat = getData() #get new data for table
    event, values = window.read(timeout=1000)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_KEY:
        window['-TABLE-'].update(values=dat)
        window.refresh()

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use option `enable_click_events` to get where you clicked on the Table element.

The format for the event will be: `('-TABLE-', '+CLICKED+', (row, col))`
It will mean the column-0 link clicked if `row` is not `None`, greater or equal then 0,  and `col` is 0.

Reduced Example Code - There's no way to change the color or underline for specific cell, so just only for clickable link.

```py
import webbrowser
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = [
    ("Link",                   "Name",   "Users", "Id",   "Authorized"),
    ("https://www.google.com", "Google", "10",    "5445", "No"),
    ("https://www.yahoo.com",  "yahoo",  "2",     "333",  "Yes"),
]
col_widths = list(map(lambda y:max(y)+2, map(lambda x:map(len, x), zip(*data))))

sg.theme("LightBlue")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))
layout = [
    [sg.Table(
        values=data[1:],
        headings=data[0],
        auto_size_columns=False,
        col_widths=col_widths,
        enable_click_events=True,
        cols_justification='lcccc',
        num_rows=10,
        key='-TABLE-',
    )],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("Check")],
]
window = sg.Window('Table', layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[:-1] == ('-TABLE-', '+CLICKED+'):
        row, col = event[-1]
        if row is not None and row >= 0 and col==0:
            url = data[row+1][0]
            webbrowser.open(url)

window.close()
```

Comment: `cols_justification` is a documented parameter for `Table`, but is absent in PySimpleGUI latest version (4.60.5).

Comment: Not all enhancements added into the PyPI version. You can upgrade your PySimpleGUI from Github, refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/4924